# Preventing Unnecessary Requests when update the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How to preventing unnecessary requests when update the input?

I tried below solution.But in the `App` file, that `search` is declared but never used. I tried something like: https://alligator.io/react/live-search-with-axios/.
What is the variable `let token` in the file`utils.js`. Should I assign `let token = localStorage.getItem ('token') to this variable;`?

**App**

```
import search from /.utils

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
    }
  }

  search = (query) => {
    axios({
       url: `/api/v1/todos/{query}`,
       method: "GET"
    })
    .then(res => {  
        this.setState({
            todos: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }) 

  render () {

    return (
        <input onChange={this.search} />    
    )
  }
}
```

**utils.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const makeRequestCreator = () => {
  let token;

  return (query) => {
    // Check if we made a request
    if(token){
      // Cancel the previous request before making a new request
      token.cancel()
    }
    // Create a new CancelToken
    token = axios.CancelToken.source()
    try{
      const res = axios(query, {cancelToken: cancel.token})
      const result = data.data
      return result;
    } catch(error) {
        if(axios.isCancel(error)) {
          // Handle if request was cancelled
          console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
        } else {
          // Handle usual errors
          console.log('Something went wrong: ', error.message)
        }
    }
  }
}

const search = makeRequestCreator()

export default search;
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use debouncing, so not to hit the API on every input change. In detail, you delay the invocation of the onChange function until a specified timeout has expired. This [article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) might help you.

Comment: How are your two code snippets related ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  in utils.js export `search` and I use in App as  `search = (query) => {`....

Comment: @Umbro no you do not use it. You just create a method of the class with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a function that delays executing of your onChange.you can use debounce function from lodash.js

```
  //  _.debounce(yourSearch function, delay time);

     search(e){
      let str = e.target.value;
      _.debounce(() => yourFunction, 500);
    }
```

Comment: I have a problem: I did: `import _, {debounce} from 'lodash';  this.search1(query) { _.debounce(() => this.search(query), 500);} ` but  it doesn't work

Comment: I made a gist file for you.take a look.https://gist.github.com/ImanRezasefat/0e8befbcbd88806b474a136dce8549ed

Comment: How can import it?